# Direct Sums of Modules.

Tags: modules, direct-sum

Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional $kG$-module. Let $M_{1},...,M_{n}$ be simple submodules of $M$ such that

$$M= \sum_{i=1}^{n} M_{i}.$$

Show that we have some subset $I \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that

$$M = \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_{i}.$$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: kevin sorry... editted

Comment: This seems to be false in all nontrivial cases, since you want the result for whatever $I$ is given. Did you perhaps intend to ask for a proof that **there exists** an $I$ for which $M$ equals the indicated direct sum?

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes i did... sorry... i'll correct it.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $i\neq j$. Suppose that $M_i\cap M_j\neq 0$, then $M_i\cap M_j=M_i=M_j$ since the $M_k$'s are simple. Can you generalize this? Proposition 7.19 here : http://www.math.hcmuns.edu.vn/~nvdong/DaiSoDaiCuong/Advanced%20Modern%20Algebra%20-%20Joseph%20J.%20Rotman.pdf gives a useful characterizations of direct sums of modules.

Comment: @Mathematician42 So since we can show that if any two submodules have elements in common implies they are the same, we generalize by selecting $i \in I$ such that $M_{i} \cap (M_{1} + ... + M_{i-1} + M_{i+1} + ... + M_{n}) = 0$. After selecting these, we have gotten rid of all the "redundent information" in a sense, and are left with what is the direct sum of a selection of those initial simple submodules?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.